# tail -n1 on latest non-empty line

Tags: bash, grep, tail

I wanted to achieve something similar to this

```
grep -v '^$' <myfile-with-blank-lines-at-the-end> | tail -n 1
```

Basically, I have a file with a unique number, followed by a comma
and I want to grab the last id, even when there might be empty lines underneath.
The goal is to use just tail

Comment: Is there something wrong with this `grep`+`tail` solution? Why do you want *just* `tail`?

Comment: No, nothing wrong, just wondering if there is a more concise solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The goal is to use just `tail`.

There is no way.

---

#### Analysis

The two tools you used were created with [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Origin) in mind:

> - Write programs that do one thing and do it well.
> - Write programs to work together.
> - Write programs to handle text streams, because that is a universal interface.

In your example they work together, passing a text stream one to another. Each does its "one thing":

- `grep`'s thing is ["search a file for a pattern"](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html),
- `tail`'s thing is ["copy the last part of a file"](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tail.html).

These things are orthogonal; there is no common component.

`tail` doesn't care of the content, in particular it doesn't care if any line is empty. In effect you cannot do what you want with sole `tail`. If anyone expanded `tail` to handle your case, I would say it's the Wrong Thing.

`grep` doesn't care if it has reached the last line. There is the `\Z` anchor designed to match "at the end of the string as well as before the final line break in the string (if any)" or even "at the end of the string as well as before all trailing line breaks in the string (if any)" (depending on flavor, see [this](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refanchors.html)). The latter would be useful to your case, but `grep` doesn't seem to support `\Z` (or anything similar) at all.

---

#### More general tools

There are tools whose "one things" are broad enough to cover the two tasks. You can certainly use a general purpose text processing tool like `sed` or `awk`.

Indeed, each of the following commands does (almost) what your original command does:

```
sed -n '/./ h; $ {g;p}'
awk '{if ($0 != "") buffer=$0} END {print buffer}'
```

Almost, because if there is no non-empty line (which also includes the case of totally empty input), there will be one empty line in the output. Your original command produces nothing in such case. We need some logic to really mimic your command. Like this:

```
sed -n '/./ h; $ {g;s/^$//;t;g;p}'
awk '{if ($0 != "") buffer=$0} END {if (buffer != "") print buffer}'
```

Even without this additional logic I find both solutions less concise than your `grep … | tail …`. No surprise here. Very simple scripts (or/and default options) for a general tool will probably do nothing interesting; while a good specialized tool is designed to do its most common task with quite simple syntax.

This means you shouldn't expect to find a single general tool that allows you to do what you want as easily as `grep … | tail …`. If the pipeline was long and complex then `sed` or `awk` *might* be the best approach, a simplifying one. But your use case is "search for lines (not) matching a pattern and pick the last one". This is exactly what `grep` and `tail` are for.

---

#### KISS

[Keep it simple and straightforward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). Your original command is very straightforward. One needs only some basic knowledge of the two tools to roughly understand what's going on. I see `grep … | tail …` and I immediately can say we're searching for some pattern and going to pick few last lines. Because this is what these tools do, respectively.

I see `awk …` or `sed …` and it can be anything. Even if some (esoteric? golfing?) language allows us to use more concise code for your particular task, I would still opt for `grep … | tail …`, especially if the code is going to last and be maintained.

---

#### Improvement

I'm able to simplify your original command a bit, but its form of `grep … | tail …` stands:

```
# original, for comparison, commented out
# grep -v '^$' | tail -n 1

# simplified
grep . | tail -n 1
```

Comment: That is enlightening !   
Funny I forgot about  
 * Write programs that do one thing and do it well.  
Which is a quote I sometimes use even outside the scope of Linux or even IT (in life !)